# Как доработать цикл while, чтобы функция возвращала кучу значений?

Tags: php, mysql

Смотрите, задача такая, мне нужно чтобы данная функция возвращала данные столько раз сколько есть в бд, но к сожалению она возвращает только первое. Цикл while внутри функции не работает. Как быть?

```
function mysql_get($mysql_tbl, $mysql_select, $mysql_recurse, $mysql_param){

if (!$mysql_tbl) {
    die('<b>Fatal error:</b> mysql_tbl is <b>null</b>;');
} else if (!$mysql_select) {
    die('<b>Fatal error:</b> mysql_select is <b>null</b>;');
} else if ($mysql_select == "all") {
    $mysql_select = "*";
} else if (!$mysql_recurse) {
    die('<b>Fatal error:</b> mysql_recurse is <b>null</b>;');
} else if ($mysql_recurse == true) {
    $mysql_recurse = true;
} else if (!$mysql_param) {
    die('<b>Fatal error:</b> mysql_param is <b>null</b>;');
}

if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '7.0.0','>=')) {
    include 'mysql.php';
}
$mysql_host = 'localhost';
$mysql_user = 'root';
$mysql_pass = '*****';
$mysql_base = 'hk_base';
$mysql_conn = mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass);
$mysql_db_conn = mysql_select_db($mysql_base);

mysql_query(" SET NAMES 'utf8' ");

if (!$mysql_conn || $mysql_db_conn) {
    mysql_error();
}

$mysql_tbl = mysql_query(' SELECT '. $mysql_select .' FROM '. $mysql_tbl .' ');

$mysql_rslt = mysql_fetch_array($mysql_tbl);

mysql_close($mysql_conn);

if ($mysql_recurse == true) {
    while ($mysql_rslt) {
        return $mysql_rslt[$mysql_param];
    }
} else {
    return $mysql_rslt[$mysql_param];
}   
}
```

Comment: а чего вы хотите от цикла, который единственную с инструкцию `return` в себе имеет?

Comment: Примеры тут http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-fetch-row.php или http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php И **читайте, что разработчики пишут в предупреждениях к функциям**

Answer (score 0):

Ознакомьтесь, пожалуйста, с базовыми знаниями. Документаций в интернете есть огромное множество.

`return` после того, как функция вернула значение - она перестает выполняться дальше.

Конкретно в Вашем случае, если не вдаваться в подробности кода, то Вам нужно выводить информацию следующим образом

```
$return = array ();
if ($mysql_recurse == true) {
    while ($mysql_rslt) {
        $return[] = $mysql_rslt[$mysql_param];
    }
    return $return; // в данном случае функция вернет массив состоящий из mysql_rslt
} else {
    return $mysql_rslt[$mysql_param];
}
```

**P.S.** и не нужно mysql использовать, особенно, когда в коде фигурирует информация о PHP 7ой версии

Comment: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 268435464 bytes) in /php/init.php on line 54

Comment: ну это уже другой вопрос, я ответил на изначальный. Но разбираться в старом коде желанием особо не горю

Comment: @Peresada про return вы заметили правильно, но сами же не пользуетесь своим утверждением. else в вашем примере не нужен

Comment: @StereoFlo я знаю, я же написал "не вдаваться в подробности кода" я просто 2 строчки добавил